# How to update elements in multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have the following array structure:

```
let cells = [
  ['foo', 'foo'],
  ['foo', 'foo']
]
```

And I want to update it so it becomes:

```
[
  ['bar', 'foo'],
  ['foo', 'foo']
]
```

I thought this would suffice:

```
cells[0][0] = 'bar';
```

But that changes `cells[1][0]` too, resulting instead in:

```
[
  ['bar', 'foo'],
  ['bar', 'foo']
]
```

How do I only change `cells[0][0]`?

Comment: You didn't show the whole picture in your question. Chance is, you first create an array, store it into the variable (with something like `let row = ['foo', 'foo']`, then use something like `let cells = [row, row]`. In this case, you _reuse_ the same object; naturally, when you change its property, all the rows are changed instead.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like in your program, you have an array with two attributes referencing the same object. This would happen in the following code:

```
let row = ["foo", "foo"]
let cells = [];
cells.push(row);
cells.push(row);
```

When you do `cells.push(row)`, you don't create a new array which will be pushed to `cells`, you instead pass the array by reference.

There is now only one array `row = ["foo", "foo"]`, referenced twice by the `cells` object. By doing `cells[0][0] = "bar"`, I would change the first element of the `row` object. Since the same object is referenced inside of the `cells` object twice, it will be the same on both positions.

Depending on your use case, you either want to clone the first array, or create a new array independently on the first array.

For your options of cloning the array, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! It was indeed a case of the array elements referring to the same object. Thought it would be something silly on my part!